# Write a function to calculate the average of two numbers.(Python.) Keeps getting a name that is not defined

Tags: python, function, raw-input

Alright, so I am new with python at the moment and I am absolutely confusing myself with such a simple task. I have to write a function to calculate the average  of two numbers, but the user must input the numbers so the average should print out.

I keep getting a a name error, name 'number2' is not defined.Below is my code.

```
number1 = raw_input("Enter number1")
number2 =raw_input("Enter number2")

def average(number1, number2):
  return (number1 + number2) / 2
avg=average = (number1,number2)
print avg
```

I'm doing something wrong and I know its obvious but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: I guess you want: `avg = average(number1, number2)` somewhere in there... after converting those input strings to `int` or `float`

Answer (score 1):

You are making incorrect call to your function. You should do:

```
#              v type-cast value to `int` as `raw_input` returns `str` object
avg = average(int(number1), int(number2))
# ^     ^ make a call to `average()` and store the returned value as `avg`
```

---

Below is the complete code sample:

```
>>> number1 = raw_input("Enter number1: ")
Enter number1: 12
>>> number2 =raw_input("Enter number2: ")
Enter number2: 45
>>> def average(number1, number2):
...   return (number1 + number2) / 2.0  # `2.0` to get floating precision
...
>>> avg = average(int(number1), int(number2))
>>> avg
28
```

**Note:** In Python 2.x, division of two `int` returns an `int` value. If you want the response as `float`, use `2.0` instead of `2` for division

Comment: Thank you! I had that before except not with avg, I knew it was a silly mistake, but I'm working on getting better, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `average` as a function, and you must use it as a function. Something like this:

```
number1 = raw_input("Enter number1")
number2 =raw_input("Enter number2")

def average(number1, number2):
  return (int(number1) + int(number2)) / 2.0

avg=average(number1,number2)
print avg
```

There were two other things too. You must convert string to integer, and to get a good average you have to divide them by 2.0 instad of 2. Onother way to solve it is to convert the string to float directly.

Comment: Dividing string by int?

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
#get number 1, number2 as integers
number1 = int(raw_input("Enter number1"))
number2 =int(raw_input("Enter number2"))
#your function as it was
def average(number1, number2):
  return (number1 + number2) / 2
#function `average` returns an int. Store that result in `avg`
avg = average(number1,number2)
#print the result
print(avg)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is taking raw_input and not converting it to an integer before arithmetical operation.

When using numbers in python, always use input() other than raw input, to save yourselves from converting raw_iniput to an integer because the input command already takes it as an int.

```
def avg(a=input('Pls enter val 1: '),b=input('Pls entr val 2: ')):
    return ((a / b) / 2.0)

a=avg()
```

And when using python 2.7 always use float values while dividing cause dividing two integers will always return int whether or not the answer is float. 
So , you can use something like this as well:

```
number1 = float(input("Enter number1"))
number2 = float(input("Enter number2"))

def average(number1, number2):
  return (number1 + number2) / 2.0
avg=average = (number1,number2)
print avg
```